# Limit results by field value using TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get the results from a table such that they are limited by the number of similar field values. For example, here are some sample records:

```
FieldValue (nvarchar)
----------
id1/mode3/path
id2/mode2/path
id3/mode3/path
id4/mode1/path
id5/mode3/path
id6/mode2/path
id7/mode2/path
id8/mode3/path
```

In which case, I only want max 2 records for each mode, so the results should be:

```
id1/mode3/path
id2/mode2/path
id3/mode3/path
id4/mode1/path
id6/mode2/path
```

How can I do this in TSQL (SQL Server 2012)?

**[Update]** Note: id, mode and path are not separate fields. They're a concatenated text value (e.g. "id1/mode3/path") in a field named FieldValue.

Comment: may I ask this fieldvalue is in 1 column or they are 3 column total

Comment: fieldvalue is one nvarchar column.

Comment: are modes fixed ? like 1,2,3

Comment: @utility: no, it can be any number (e.g. mode0287).

Comment: ids limited ,max value ?

Comment: id can be any number, but it doesn't matter. Grouping by mode is more important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use windowed function and string manipulation function to split data:

```
WITH cte AS
( SELECT 
       FieldValue
      ,[id]        = LEFT(FieldValue, CHARINDEX('/', FieldValue)-1)
      ,[mode]      = SUBSTRING(FieldValue,
                               CHARINDEX('/', FieldValue)+1,
                               CHARINDEX('/',RIGHT(FieldValue,LEN(FieldValue)
                               -CHARINDEX('/', FieldValue)))-1)
  FROM #tab
), cte2 AS
(
  SELECT FieldValue, r = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mode ORDER BY id)
  FROM cte
)
SELECT FieldValue
FROM cte2
WHERE r <= 2
ORDER BY FieldValue;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/410762)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════════════════╗
║   FieldValue   ║
╠════════════════╣
║ id1/mode3/path ║
║ id2/mode2/path ║
║ id3/mode3/path ║
║ id4/mode1/path ║
║ id6/mode2/path ║
╚════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 2):

Lad2025's answer does the job, but I would consider improving your table design (schema), if possible.

In order to avoid computing those substrings and ordering based on it (it is expensive for large data), you can add new columns to the table. They can be computed when FieldValue is inserted or, if this is not possible, added as persisted computed columns:

```
id NVARCHAR(10) AS LEFT(FieldValue, CHARINDEX('/', FieldValue)-1) PERSISTED,
mode NVARCHAR(10) AS SUBSTRING(FieldValue,
                               CHARINDEX('/', FieldValue)+1,
                               CHARINDEX('/',RIGHT(FieldValue,LEN(FieldValue)
                               -CHARINDEX('/', FieldValue)))-1) PERSISTED
```

Thus, the query is greatly simplified:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT FieldValue, r = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mode ORDER BY id)
  FROM yourtable
)
SELECT FieldValue
FROM cte 
WHERE r <= 2
ORDER BY FieldValue;
```

This design also allows to index added columns to obtain greater performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte
as
(
      select row_number() over(partition by mode order by mode) as cnt,*
      from FieldValue
)
select id,mode,path
from cte 
where cnt <= 2
```

try this query.

Comment: id, mode and path are not separate fields. They're a concatenated text value (e.g. "id1/mode3/path") in a field named FieldValue.

Answer (score 1):

try,

```
select md from(
select md,row_number() over (partition by replace(stuff(md,1,CHARINDEX('/',md),''),
(stuff(md,1,CHARINDEX('/',md,CHARINDEX('/',md)+1)-1,'')),'')
order by left(md,CHARINDEX('/',md))) as r from @t) t
where r<=2 order by md
```

sample data

```
declare @t table(md varchar(50)) insert into @t values
('id1/mode3/path'),
('id2/mode2/path'),
('id3/mode3/path'),
('id4/mode1/path'),
('id5/mode3/path'),
('id6/mode2/path'),
('id7/mode2/path'),
('id8/mode3/path')
```

Comment: Why do you assume that `/path` is hardcoded in every string?